# An own approach to Angularjs validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, angular.js

### **Introduction**

So i am building a SPA with AngularJS. The application provides a large number of `<input>` elements and can be seen as a huge form.

However, i am not using an actual `<form>` element because of the applications architecture. Once everything is filled, all of the data will be submitted by a single button, though.

This has lead to the problem that i can not use Angular's build-in form validation. I was forced to write my own implementation.

### **The issue**

What follows is my approach to validate the stuff. Everything works fine for me and gets the job done. Nevertheless, i would like to hear the opinions of some advanced or maybe even professional colleagues on how good or bad said approach is and where it could be improved.

**HTML**

This is a snippet from the applications 'form'. To maintain better readability, i've stripped out the ng-model attributes.

```
<div>
    <label for="searchClient">Kundennummer</label>
    <input validate-string type="text" id="searchClient">

    <label for="recName">Name*</label>
    <input validate-string type="text" id="recName">                 
 </div>
```

As you can see, validation is triggered via a directive restricted to attribute.

**The directive**

```
app.directive('validateString',function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element){
        var el = angular.element(element);
        el.attr('valid','nope');

        element.bind('input',function(){
            if (element[0].value !== ""){
                el.removeAttr('valid');
            }
            else{el.attr('valid','false');}
        })
    }
  }
});
```

The directive sets a default attribute of valid="false" to every element the directive is attached to. If an input is made, the attribute is removed. Once everything is done and the user decides to submit, a validation function will fire:

**validate()**

```
Shipment.prototype.validate = function(){
   var inputs = $document.find('input');
   var inValidElements = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i<inputs.length;i++){

     if(inputs[i].attributes.valid !== undefined && inputs[i].attributes.valid !== ""){
         inValidElements++;
     }
   }

     console.log(inValidElements); // Here we can handle those invalidElements
    };
```

validate() will look up all `<input>` elements on the page and set a default number of invalid elements of zero. Then, it will take each of those elements, check whether or not it has an attribute of `valid` and if so, increment the invalidElements counter. At this point, further handling of those elements would be possible.

### **Conclusion**

Would you appreciate this approach of validating a pseudo-form?

Answer (score 2):

While your code works, I would have structured it differently. I would suggest reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/677526) on StackOverflow.

In your position, I'd have written a directive to place on the outer container that holds all of the inputs, and I would have made your `validate` function a part of the directive itself. By doing this, you might be able to avoid looking for elements that have a specific class set; you could simply use the values of the datamodel to determine that. I would probably use an object to hold key/value pairs, and use the input ID as the key (with the validity value as the object).

I don't have sample code at the moment (and it seems that, for this site, sample code is essential to a good answer) but I'll try to mock something up tomorrow, perhaps.

Comment: Thank you very much so far, i will try to implement your concept. Nevertheless, i would appreciate a sample, as you suggested.